# create clean url with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I need to generate clean url for my website, and after a week of searching i was able to arrive at this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# remove .php extention from web pages
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,END]
```

the rewrite rule is working perfectly 
e.g "mysite.com/user.php" result in "mysite.com/user"
"mysite.com/user/profile.php" result in "mysite.com/user/profile"

Now, the issue I'm having is this;
when i add query rule like the following

```
# remove .php extention from web pages and query
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*?)/?$ /$1.php?user=$2 [NC,END]
```

the query works for link like this; `mysite.com/user/stephen`
but when i try to visit `mysite.com/user` again it send me to the 404 page

now these are my aims:

> 1) If someone visit `mysite.com/page.php` or  `mysite.com/page` it should
>   display `mysite.com/page`
>
> 2) I should be able to query the stephen data
>   from `user.php` with this link `mysite.com/user/stephen` without having
>   previous issue i'm trying to solve

thanks in advance, Stephen.

Comment: have you tried something like an htaccess simulator: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)